# Mongoose query to find documents contains a particular key in an inner object in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My Current mongo db structure is like this

```
Room: {
// ... other data
 users : {
   userId1 : {
    //  other user info ...
   }
   userId2 : {
    // other  user info ...
   }
  }
}
```

And now I want to write a mongoose query to find all the rooms which contains the userId `123`.
Can you please let me know how I can achieve this with `Room.find` method in `Mongoose`.

** In my schema `users` is an Object not an array, And I cannot change it as this structure is imported from Firebase DB with and existing data. So its a limitation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First confirm that you want all rooms or room(one document), because you mention all rooms with "findOne", findOne will return only one document.

Anyway if that document contains these userId1, userId2 fields then it can be achieved by $or operator in mongodb as follows

Before the mongoose query execution make sure you have done the schema creation, mongodb connections.

```
      if need all rooms:
            Room.find({$or:[{'users.userId1.userid':"123"}, 
                      {'users.userId2.userid':"123"}]},function(err,result)
                        {
                          //multiple rooms
                        });

       else one room:
               Room.findOne({$or:[{'users.userId1.userid':"123"}, 
                            {'users.userId2.userid':"123"}]},function(err,result)
                            {
                             //single room
                            })
```

Comment: sorry my mistake, I need all rooms,

Comment: userid is not the inner key, userId1 is an example, that could be 123

Comment: then your structure should be like this right? Room: {
// ... other data
 users : {
   userId1 :"123"
   userId2 :"345"

Comment: no man, its like this. Room: { // ... other data users : { 123 :{name: "prasath", gender: "male"},  { 456 :{name: "asad", gender: "male"}}}

Comment: Please make sure the mongodb room schema structure, because you cant able to get the document by fileds. eg: users : { 123 :{name: "prasath", gender: "male"}} once you create schema with this filed name as 123 it will remain the same whatever number of documents inserted into Room collection.

Comment: yes userid will never change, for example for one user its 123 & for other user its 456 etc... And I don't want to update it, I just want to fetch all the rooms containing a user by userId. thats it.